# A function in $H(div)$ not in $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain. I am not sure what a function in

$H($div$) = \{ u\in L^2(\Omega):\nabla\cdot u \in L^2(\Omega) \}$

but not in

$H^1 = \{ u\in L^2(\Omega): \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Omega) \}$

would look like. I know that at least two space dimensions are needed, but I haven't figured out how to construct an example.

Edit: I forgot to specify for a bounded domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**: 
For concreteness we suppose our bounded domain contains the origin in the interior, but in the general case we can do a translation.

Take
$$ u(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} H(y) \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
where $H$ is the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). $u$ is a bounded function defined on a bounded domain, so $u$ is in $L^2$. The divergence of $u$ can be computed explicitly to be 0. But $\partial_y u$ is equal to the Dirac $\delta$ along the $x$-axis, and is not in $L^2$.

**Example**: One may say that the previous example is too singular. We can give a slightly less singular example. assume the origin is on the boundary of your domain. Let 
$$ u(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-y}{r} \\ \frac{x}{r} \end{pmatrix} $$
Again $u$ is a bounded (smooth) function on a bounded domain so is in $L^2$. You can directly compute that $\nabla \cdot u = 0$.

But 
$$ \partial_y u = \begin{pmatrix} - x^2 / r^3 \\ - xy/r^3 \end{pmatrix} $$
within the sector $\{x^2 \geq y^2\}$ you have that the first factor is bounded below by $1/r$, which is not square integrable.

Comment: A similar approach also works in higher dimensions. Start with an arbitrary vector field $V$ that is tangent to the spheres. Then for any radial function $A$, the vector field $AV$ is divergence free. So all you need to do is to choose $A$ to be fast decaying (to guarantee that $u\in L^2$) and high frequency (so that $V \partial A$ is not in $L^2$).

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I didn't make enough specifications on my problem. I do work on bounded domains, so I was hoping to find an example in a bounded domain. Also, is there something that doesn't involve computing the curl? My understanding of functional analysis is fairly limited, so I don't know how the curl relates to $H^1$.

Comment: @Ken: in regards to curl, you argue by contradiction. If $u$ were in $H^1$, then $\partial_x (u_y) \in L^2$ and $\partial_y (u_x) \in L^2$ hence $\nabla\times u \in L^2$. No functional analysis needed, just basic multivariable calculus. I will edit with bounded domains.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I think I figured out where my understanding was too limited.